# Search a string in each row of a pandas Dataframe and return the column names where found

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to find a string in the DataFrame and return the column names upon match.

In the below example, I am trying to find the columns where "SRC" appears, not sure if I am close, but it returns all the column names instead of only the relevant ones. I 'm sure I am doing something silly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['foo SRC','bar','baz'], 'col2':['foo','bar','baz'],'col3':['SRC','bar','SRC'],
                  'col4':['SRC','SRC','SRC']})

df['col_list']= '/'.join(df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('SRC')).any().loc[lambda x : x].index)


Actual Result:
---------------------------------------------
col1    |col2   |col3   |col4   |col_list
--------|-------|-------|-------|----------------
foo SRC |foo    |SRC    |SRC    |col1/col3/col4
bar     |bar    |bar    |SRC    |col1/col3/col4
baz     |baz    |SRC    |SRC    |col1/col3/col4

Expected:

col1    |col2   |col3   |col4   |col_list
--------|-------|-------|-------|----------------
foo SRC |foo    |SRC    |SRC    |col1/col3/col4
bar     |bar    |bar    |SRC    |col4
baz     |baz    |SRC    |SRC    |col3/col4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with [`df.dot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df['col_list']=df.applymap(lambda x: 'SRC' in x).dot(df.columns + '/').str[:-1]
```

Or [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and `df.dot`:

```
df['col_list']=df.apply(lambda x: 
                  x.str.contains('SRC',na=False)).dot(df.columns + '/').str[:-1]
print(df)
```

---

```
      col1 col2 col3 col4        col_list
0  foo SRC  foo  SRC  SRC  col1/col3/col4
1      bar  bar  bar  SRC            col4
2      baz  baz  SRC  SRC       col3/col4
```

Comment: Thanks! That was fast :)

Comment: always nice to see `dot` solution :) +1